# Laravel Eloquent Query to have values first instead of column name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to run below query in laravel eloquent, but i'm unable to do so.

```
SELECT * FROM vehicle_unavailabilities WHERE ("2021/06/05" NOT BETWEEN from_date and to_date) AND ("2021/06/07" NOT BETWEEN from_date and to_date)
```

If i try

```
->whereNotBetween("2021/06/05",['from_date',['to_date'])
```

it gives me error of **column "2021/06/05" not found.** How can i achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

This should be your column name.

`SELECT * FROM vehicle_unavailabilities WHERE ("COLUMN_NAME" NOT BETWEEN from_date and to_date) AND ("COLUMN_NAME" NOT BETWEEN from_date and to_date)`

`->whereNotBetween("COLUMN_NAME",['from_date', 'to_date'])`

Comment: I think they want to use a fixed date rather than a column name.

Comment: But it is not meeting my requirement. I need value in front and compare it with the values from the table fields. SQL query is properly being executed from phpmyadmin sql query

Comment: But where condition needs column_name to compare values? Please paste your SQL Query here..

Comment: Thanks @Jayant, i figured it out, 
->whereRaw("? BETWEEN `from_date` AND `to_date`", [$from_date])

Answer (score 0):

```
->whereRaw("? BETWEEN `from_date` AND `to_date`", [$from_date])
```

This resolved the issue.